# What is the proper return code for C_Login when a CKU_SO attempts to log into a non-initialized token?

Tags: pkcs11

Looking at the PKCS#11 2.4 spec, `C_Login` returns `CKR_USER_PIN_NOT_INITIALIZED` when a "normal user's PIN has not yet been initialized with `C_InitPIN`".  However, I can not find anything that would be analogous to a situation when a user calls `C_Login` for a `CKU_SO` user on a token that has not been initialized using `C_InitToken`.

Is this just a hole in the specification or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is a great question! I think that it is indeed a hole in the specification: there is no return value for when we are trying to use a token that has never been initialized, not in log in, and not in open session. I am about to post a similar question.